# Label a storage volume in Windows Compact 2013

Tags: c++, windows, label, storage, wce

I have an (non-MFC) Windows application written in C++ (Visual Studio 2013) running on a small device running Windows Compact 2013.

The device has two storage volumes (internal flash memory and SD Card)

If I connect the device to a Windows PC via USB cable, the volumes are mounted and I can see them as two separate drives inside Windows Explorer. I am then able to change the label of each volume inside Explorer (right click on the drive -> Properties -> type in a new label)

I would like to have the ability to label the volumes from my application running on the device.

I have tried various Compact 2013 API calls without success (obviously the Compact API is far more restrictive than the full Win32 API).

I have even tried to call a script file to call the LABEL command. Also without success.

Can anyone offer me any advice about how to accomplish this? Any help would be much appreciated

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the solution was surprisingly simple. I added an `autorun.inf` file to the root folder of the device with the following content

```
[autorun] 
label=My Label
```

This had exactly the effect that I was looking to achieve.